# How can I require that a parser only returns full matches and not partial in boost spirit?

Tags: boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

In my parser, sometimes the grammar accommodates a match on just the first section of an input string. This seems to be normal behavior for phrase_parse(), but is not what I'm looking for in my application.

How can I require that the whole input string match the grammar for a successful parse, rather than returning success on shorter matches that don't consume all of the input string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just require `qi::eoi` at the end:

```
bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, grammar >> eoi, skipper);
```

This also works to discard branches that didn't match all input:

```
myrule = (legA >> eoi) | (legB >> eoi) | (legC >> eoi);
```

See also

- [Boost Spirit Signals Successful Parsing Despite Token Being Incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864978/boost-spirit-signals-successful-parsing-despite-token-being-incomplete/12868247#12868247)
- [boost spirit istream iterator giving false positives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20527516/boost-spirit-istream-iterator-giving-false-positives/20528662#20528662)